# What is the logical explanation behind this lines of code that included "for" loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, math, logic

I have some trouble understanding the logic behind these following lines of code. Can anyone please help explain why these codes produced the following result?

```
  public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int n;
   for(n = 1; n <= 5; n++)
       System.out.println(mystery(n));
}
public static int mystery(int k){
     int x,y;
    y = k;
    for(x=1; x<= (k -1); x++)
        y = y * (k-x);
    return y;
}
```

These are the results:

1 2 6 24 120

Comment: This is a factorial series, following is the explanation :

1! = 1

2! = 2*1 = 2

3! = 3*2*1 = 6

4! = 4*3*2*1 = 24

5! = 5*4*3*2*1 = 120

Answer (score 0):

In main, you declared a new int called n. In the for loop, you initialized n to 1 and then ran the for loop until n > 5. If we expand the for loop, the calls you make are:

```
System.out.println(mystery(1));
System.out.println(mystery(2));
System.out.println(mystery(3));
System.out.println(mystery(4));
System.out.println(mystery(5));
```

In mystery(), you declare two ints: x and y. You initialize y to k (the parameter you received from the method call).
In the for loop, you initialized x to 1 and ran the for loop until x > (k-1). This runs the loop k-1 times. Then you multiplied y by (k-x) each time you ran the loop. When x > (k-1), you returned y.

Let's take mystery(5) for example. I'll expand the for loop in mystery() so you can visualize it better.

```
int x,y;
y = 5;

y = y * (5 - 1); //y*4
y = y * (5 - 2); //y*3
y = y * (5 - 3); //y*2
y = y * (5 - 4); //y*1

return y;
```

Mathematically, mystery(5) = 5*4*3*2*1 = 120
So, mystery() is the factorial function. mystery(5) = 5!, mystery(4) = 4!, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Lets first understand what mystery() does.
Lets say int k = 4 for an example,

```
y = k // y becomes 4
```

In the for loop we we iterate for x = 1 to x = (k-1) i.e 3
in the for loop ultimately, y becomes 4*3*2*1 = 24

That is why when n is 4 in your main method, you get the output as 24.

In short the mystery function calculates factorial for n=1 to n=5
Therefore the output is factorials of 1 to 5

i.e.  `1 2 6 24 120`